# Image swap problems

Tags: javascript

I am using an inline onclick to toggle two images that are used on the page as tabs. The swap does great but when the page reloads the images revert to the home image. I would like for the image to stay as the "selected" image until another tab is clicked.

```
 <img id="image3" src="images/charts1.png" style="display:inline;" onclick="document.getElementById('image3').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('image4').style.display='inline';" "/>

    <img id="image4" src="images/charts2.png" style="display:none;" onclick="document.getElementById('image4').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('image3').style.display='inline';"/>
```

My script

```
<script>
    if (document.images) { 
        img1on = new Image();
        img1on.src = "images/over1.jpg"; 
        img1off = new Image(); 
        img1off.src = "images/notover.jpg"; 
        img2on = new Image();
        img2on.src = "images/over2.jpg"; 
        img2off = new Image(); 
        img2off.src = "images/notover.jpg"; 
    }
    function imgOn(imgName) {
        if (document.images) {
            document[imgName].src = eval(imgName + "on.src");}
    }
    function imgOff(imgName) {
        if (document.images) {
            document[imgName].src = eval(imgName + "off.src");}
        }
</script>
```

Comment: I see a jQuery tag, but your JavaScript doesn't utilize jQuery at all.

Comment: do you want javascript to hold the image src values after page postbacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sounds of it, you want information from Javascript to maintain a state even after page refresh so you will need to use either a cookie or localstorage to store the active tab or image id or some other meaningful information to relate back to it.

Here is a solution that will use localStorage if it's available and fall back to using a cookie.

```
function imgOn(imgName) {
        if (document.images) {
            document[imgName].src = eval(imgName + "on.src");}
storeUpdate(imgName, imgName + "on.src");
    }
    function imgOff(imgName) {
        if (document.images) {
            document[imgName].src = eval(imgName + "off.src");}
storeUpdate(imgName, imgName + "on.src");
        }

function storeUpdate(key, value){
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
  {
  // Yes! localStorage and sessionStorage support
localStorage.setItem(key, value);
  }
else
  {
  // Sorry! No web storage support..
var exdays = 10; // Number of days before cookie will expire
setCookie(key, value, exdays);
  }
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

Then on page load you can check if any of these cookies are present:

```
function getImages(imgName){
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
  {
  // Yes! localStorage and sessionStorage support
return localStorage.getItem(imgName);
  }
else
  {
  // Sorry! No web storage support..
return getCookie(imgName);
  }
}
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var c_value = document.cookie;
var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
if (c_start == -1)
  {
  c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
  }
if (c_start == -1)
  {
  c_value = null;
  }
else
  {
  c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
  var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
  if (c_end == -1)
  {
c_end = c_value.length;
}
c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
}
return c_value;
}
```

Comment: I can agree with that. So how do I do that? Can I set the state in jquery with a line or two?

Comment: I've updated above to reflect using a localStorage solution with a cookie fallback.

Comment: can't get it to work because my network has cookies blocked and who knows what else.